# Join left 4 tables, or Union all Sql

Tags: sql, join, left-join, union

This question is kind of complex because mix up 4 tables in a single SQL query. I've already developed the query but it still returns different amount of rows than the expected.

Users

```
id_user  |   name
  1           A
  2           B
  3           C
  4           D
  5           E
```

Community

```
 id_following  |    id_follower | id_followed
    1                   3               4
    2                   3               5
```

Sharing

```
  id_share | id_post_shared | id_sharer | id_user_post
     1              7           5           1
     2              8           4           2
     3              9           5           4
```

Posts

```
    id_post | id_user_post | post
     1              4           Hi
     2              5           Hello
     3              2           Hey you
     4              3           come on
     5              4           here is good
     6              5           go home 
     7              1           lets go home
     8              2           go away
     9              4           come here
    10              1           show
```

I want to retrieve posts of users I follow (user 3) plus those posts this same people I follow have shared with someone else (like a retweet).

So from the tables I would expect this output (8 results)

```
  1             4           Hi
  2             5           Hello
  5             4           here is good
  6             5           go home 
  7             1           lets go home (shared by 5)
  8             2           go away (shared by 4)
  9             4           come here (shared by 5)
  9             4           come here
```

(realise that #9 repeats because is a post of someone I follow and at the same time was shared or retweeted by user 5)

This is my code but after several tests I'm not sure if what I want follows this pattern

```
SELECT 
    u.name AS n, p.post AS t
FROM  
    users AS u
LEFT JOIN  
    community AS c ON u.id_user = c.id_followed
LEFT JOIN 
    sharing AS r ON r.id_sharer = c.id_followed
LEFT JOIN 
    posts AS p ON p.id_user = c.id_followed OR p.id_user = r.id_sharer
WHERE 
    c.id_follower = 3  
    AND p.id_user != 3
```

Comment: "posts AS p ON p.id_user = c.id_followed OR p.id_user = r.id_sharer" won't bring back all posts because its left joined on the community and sharing table.

Comment: what should I use instead

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this version gives you post 9 twice:

```
DECLARE 
    @userIcareabout AS TINYINT
SET 
    @userIcareabout = 3 
SELECT
    p.id_post,
    p.id_user_post,
    p.post
FROM
    Posts AS p
WHERE
    p.id_post IN 
    (
    SELECT
        id_post AS post
    FROM
        Posts
    WHERE
        id_user_post IN 
        (
        SELECT 
            id_followed 
        FROM 
            Community
        WHERE
            id_follower = @userIcareabout
        )
    )
UNION ALL   
SELECT
    p.id_post,
    p.id_user_post,
    p.post
FROM
    Posts AS p
WHERE
    p.id_post IN    
    (
    SELECT  
        id_post_shared AS post,
        id_sharer AS poster
    FROM
        Sharing 
    WHERE
        id_user_post IN 
        (
        SELECT 
            id_followed 
        FROM 
            Community
        WHERE
            id_follower = @userIcareabout
        )
    )
```

Comment: thank you for your approach, so you mean that It wont retrieve duplicates at all?

Comment: It'll retrieve them, but just once.  So post 9 will only show up once.

Comment: I was testing yor code, works as you said. What would it need to show that extra row.

Comment: I edited the query so that it will show the extra row.